# Merging multiple columns with dates in a single dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe as per below

```
D1          P2open  D2          P2high  D3          P2low   D4          P2close
1/2/1997    1259    1/2/1997    1263    1/3/1997    1247    1/2/1997    1250
1/3/1997    1252    1/4/1997    1260    1/5/1997    1252    1/3/1997    1257
1/6/1997    1254    1/6/1997    1271    1/6/1997    1254    1/5/1997    1270
1/7/1997    1270    1/8/1997    1289    1/7/1997    1270    1/7/1997    1285
1/8/1997    1280    1/9/1997    1294    1/8/1997    1280    1/8/1997    1289
1/9/1997    1285    1/10/1997   1290    1/9/1997    1285    1/10/1997   1287
```

I only know how to merge this way, but I dont know how to expand it to merge all of them, can you advise me please?

```
df = df[['D9', 'P3close']].merge(df[['D4', 'P2close']], how='left', left_on='D9', right_on='D4')
```

Results wanted

```
    D1          P2open  P2high  P2low   P2close
    1/2/1997    1259    1263    nan     1250
    1/3/1997    1252    nan     1247    1257
    1/6/1997    1254    1271    1254    nan
    1/7/1997    1270    nan     1270    1285
    1/8/1997    1280    1289    1280    1289
    1/9/1997    1285    1294    1285    nan
```

They all use D1 to merge

Answer (score 0):

You can just chain them all together, though it is rather ugly. If it is a possibility you may consider storing the data in a different fashion.

```
df[['D1', 'P2open']].set_index('D1').merge(df[['D2', 'P2high']].set_index('D2'), how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)\
    .merge(df[['D3', 'P2low']].set_index('D3'), how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)\
    .merge(df[['D4', 'P2close']].set_index('D4'), how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)

          P2open  P2high   P2low  P2close
D1
1/2/1997    1259  1263.0     NaN   1250.0
1/3/1997    1252     NaN  1247.0   1257.0
1/6/1997    1254  1271.0  1254.0      NaN
1/7/1997    1270     NaN  1270.0   1285.0
1/8/1997    1280  1289.0  1280.0   1289.0
1/9/1997    1285  1294.0  1285.0      NaN
```